# previous and next data-toggle inside modal only work with photos that have already been paginated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**edit**

So what happens when I attempt to click previous but it hadn't been paginate yet?  There is no error or message in Heroku. Does it return something? My previous method means that if there is a previous link that there are definitely more photos.

The previous and next buttons in my modal work fine until I get to the end of the photos that have been paginated. So for example there are 9 photos per_page. If I am on the first page of photos and I click previous on the last photo, it will not open the 10th photo. The link is correct but the modal won't open the photo because it has not yet been paginated by the controller.

**show.html.erb**

```
<% @photos.in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row instagram">
      <% group.each do |photo| %>
        <a data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.id}"%>>
          ...
        <div class="modal" id=<%="#{photo.id}"%> tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"> 
        ... 
        <a class="modaldirection" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" href=<%="#"+"#{photo.previous_modal.id}"%>>
```

**class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base**

```
def previous_modal
  if self.class.where("id < ?", id).last == nil
    return self
  else
    return self.class.where("id < ?", id).last
  end  
end
```

**class UsersController**

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @photos = @user.photos.approved.order('created_at desc').paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 9)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
end
```

Comment: is this supposed to be a gallery showing all `@photos`? then why do you make groups of three? usually, when making a gallery, on the server you output a list of all photos, then use JavaScript to make it an interactive gallery...

Comment: @mb21 it allows for rows otherwise you would have to paginate as col-4. I wrote this code awhile ago but there was reasons for it. I don't think it effects the question if am using rails to paginate the photos. You are suggesting doing all the front end for url photos in Js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I quite understand the question. But usually, when making a gallery, you output a list of all photos on the server...

```
<div class="galleria">
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag photo %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

...then use JavaScript to make it an interactive gallery. For example using [Galleria](http://galleria.io):

```
<script>
  Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
  Galleria.run('.galleria');
</script>
```